# matplotlib 1.5.x installation problems in python3.5 linux (CentOS7)

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, matplotlib, easy-install

I am trying to install `Matplotlib 1.5.0 /1.5.1` version in my `CentOS7 -- Python3.5` active machine.

I have resolved all the dependencies stated in the INSTALL file and also have updated setuptools to latest one.

However, to my bad luck I am not able to resolve this one particular issue shown in the image.  [issue in installing matplotlib in python3.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnl6n.png)

I have tried following ways of install

1. pip3 install matplotlib==1.5.1
2. easy_install-3.5 -m matplotlib

Both results in same above issue. I am clueless on what is the problem. Anyone solved this issue?

Comment: If you do not manage to resolve the error you could always try [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) as a plan b, which I find works more reliably than using the OS repos.

Comment: It seems that you don't have C compiler set on your machine; try `CC=gcc pip3 install matplotlib==1.5.1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing it via

`rpm -Uvh`

Find the rpm package here [matplotlib.rpm](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python-matplotlib)